# Converting a Response Buffer to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, buffer

In AWS, I am issuing a get request through Lambda with the https module. I am able to return the data, but it is in the buffer format when I call `callback(null, obj)`

```
https.get(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        var foo = (JSON.stringify(d));
        var foo1 = d.toString('utf8');

        var obj = {
            bar: foo,
            bar1: foo2
        };

        callback(null, obj);
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Returns this:

```
Response:
{
   "bar": "{\"type\":\"Buffer\",\"data\":[31,153,38,35,...]}",
   "bar1": "[{\"app_id\":1111111,\"user_id\":111111,....\"}]"
}
```

How do I convert this to JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. With tomfa's code found here: [BinArraytoJson](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/tomfa/706d10fed78c497731ac.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) I simply did:

```
var binArrayToJson = function(binArray) {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < binArray.length; i++) {
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(binArray[i]));
    } 
    return JSON.parse(str)
}
```

Then: 
`JSON.parse(binArrayToJson(yourBinArray));`

Comment: Plugging a library I wrote for a similar situation: You could also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/js0xn